# Why do people say that 'power flows' into or out of a component in an electric circuit?

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, energy-conservation, power

Currently, I am learning about electric circuits, and how to apply the basic concepts of physics, like work and energy. But I keep running into the same phrase--on Wikipedia, my textbooks, everywhere--

Wikipedia: [Electric Power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_power)

> electric power can flow either into or out of a component

This doesn't make any sense to me. Power is supposed to be defined as the time rate of change of work, so how can it 'flow' anywhere, its a rate. It makes sense to say that energy 'flows' places, since that's a quantity, but why would you say that the rate at which energy is transferred, i.e. power, flows somewhere?

Comment: You're right. It's the energy that's flowing. Maybe they should use a word other than flow for power. But the point of the wikipedia statement is that either energy is flowing in (power going into component is positive), or flowing out (power going into component is negative... or equivalently power is going out of component).

Comment: So what they really mean is 'X joules of energy are flowing into/out of the component per second'?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not the first, nor the last, to find the phrase "power flow" somehow *wrong*.  For example, from W J Beaty's [article on electrical misconceptions](http://amasci.com/miscon/eleca.html):

> ELECTRIC POWER FLOWS FROM GENERATOR TO CONSUMER? Wrong. Electric power
>   cannot be made to flow. Power is defined as "flow of energy." Saying
>   that power "flows" is silly. It's as silly as saying that the stuff in
>   a moving river is named "current" rather than named "water." Water is
>   real, water can flow, flows of water are called currents, but we
>   should never make the mistake of believing that water's motion is a
>   type of substance. Talking of "current" which "flows" confuses
>   everyone. The issue with energy is similar. Electrical energy is real,
>   it is sort of like a stuff, and it can flow along. When electric
>   energy flows, the flow is called "electric power." But electric power
>   has no existence of its own. Electric power is the flow rate of
>   another thing; electric power is an energy current. Energy flows, but
>   power never does, just as water flows but "water current" never does.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you think about electric power, which includes current (notion of [flux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flux)), then you'll end with the conclusion that if there's no flow, there is no power.

Comment: Right, but its the energy in Joules that's flowing in or out of the component, not the measure of power itself I thought, the power is just a measure of how fast the flow is